# Flatfile CMS that allows multiple content blocks

Tags: cms

I have been playing around with many flat file CMSs  - Baun, Phile and Pico to mention a few.  I like the idea of TWIG templates and crisp, clear markdown along with the concept of using meta data in the .md file to provide instructions to the Twig template.  My initial thought was that I could combine these capabilities in a powerful way with a CSS3 framework such as Bulma to create crisp, clean, modern web pages.  Howver, there is consistently the same issue - as far as I can tell you can define only one content block in a markdown file. To apply varying styling to different parts of the content you need to dip down into HTML which I can do but I cannot really expect my content developers to do.  Is there a simple flatfile CMS that does allow multiple content blocks in markdown.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of anybody who runs into this question.  I have now evaluated many flatfile CMS alternatives.  The clear winner is [Grav](http://getgrav.org).  With Grav you can create multiple content blocks, embed sub pages etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is another new flat file markdown CMS in PHP with the support of blocks. I is in heavy development and has a nice concept about the block definition in markdown and the block rendering via xpath statements. It's called "Reboot CMS" and you can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/shaack/reboot-cms

Answer (score 0):

- Wonder CMS - ITS TINY! (sub 100kb), "blocks" plugin
- Pico CMS - like 300kb, "blocks" plugin
- Bludit CMS- Very "potent", 5mb
- Grav CMS - The big boy of Flat File CMS's 40mb (about, with admin)